# CURL PHP (Wamp) follows Javascript windows.location redirection?

Tags: php, curl

**My problem is related to curl in a php file that follows the Javascript  windows.location returns by the server and I cannot succeed to bypass that behavior**

In fact I have written a script that connect to a website with a form for user authentication. The script works perfectly in its globality :

- 1st Request : Get Request to obtain a PHP Session in a Cookie
- 2nd Request : Post Request with cookie and Post Data containing user/password

Problem : I am always redirected by a javascript function in the server answer by a windows.location=XXXX

For Information I use WampServer Version 2.5  / PHP 5.5.12

My script is called via a web-browser with this : http://localhost/glpiv2/rechercheDerniersSuivisV2.php

---

#### First Time I create a cookie

```
function createCookie (){   

  global $proxy;
  global $proxyauth;
  global $cookies_file;
  global $timeout;

  $url='https://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx/glpi/index.php';
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  // Proxy Authentication, keep cool with security
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  0);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , false);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko','DNT: 1','Connection: Keep-Alive'));

  // => WRITE A NEW COOKIE FILE
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies_file);

  // => ESTABLISH A NEW SESSION
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 

  $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); 

  //  If Error
   if(curl_errno($ch)){
      // Le message d'erreur correspondant est affiché
      echo "ERREUR curl_exec : ".curl_error($ch);
    } 

  curl_close($ch);  
}
```

**Server response Header of the first Request**

```
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3c5939450c6811b8df981f83c9539f64; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, precheck=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 253
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Cookie is being created with PHPSESSID : OK

---

#### Second time I do a POST request with the newly created cookie to authenticate with a real user / password

```
function authenticateSession(){

  echo "Lancement de authenticateSession";
  global $proxy;
  global $proxyauth;
  global $cookies_file;
  global $timeout;
  global $authenticationGLPIPost;

  $url='https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/glpi/login.php';

  $ch1 = curl_init(); 

  // Proxy SSL and other stuff
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  0);

  // Post preparation
  curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST , TRUE);

  // POST DATA with variable containing user / password
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $authenticationGLPIPost);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies_file);
  curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  

  $file_contents = curl_exec($ch1); 
  curl_close($ch1);     
 }
```

**Server Response header of the 2nd Request**

```
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, precheck=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 269
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<script language=javascript>
   NomNav = navigator.appName;
     if (NomNav=='Konqueror'){
        window.location="/glpi/front/central.php?tokonq=fsrb7s";
     } else {
        window.location="/glpi/front/central.php";
     }
  </script>
```

=> Problem with javascript windows.location redirection here in the response, that redirect me to http://localhost/glpi/front/central.php

Server response is displayed in the webbrowser.

I suspect that the web browser does execute the Javascript returned and redirect me
I verify that with a proxy interceptor and altering the server response I mean when I supress the Javascript bloc Or if I change the parameter of windows.location the redirect modify its behaviour

---

**I try not being redirected with no success each of these options but no one works**

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
```

That mean for the first time I run the script and these 2 functions are called I am always redirected on the website page of authentication success that mean with the relative path /glpi/front/central.php.

Comment: curl surely cannot be redirected; it does not implement javascript. You haven't explained why you think curl is following the redirection.  Please do so, then we will have a chance to understand what the question is :).

Comment: Hi sourcejedi ! Let me explain that when I catch (with proxy interceptor : Burp Proxy) and modify the server response I mean that when I suppress the bloc <script language=javascript>
   NomNav = navigator.appName;
     if (NomNav=='Konqueror'){
        window.location="/glpi/front/central.php?tokonq=fsrb7s";
     } else {
        window.location="/glpi/front/central.php";
     }
  </script> then everything works as expected that mean I can continue my other tasks as I am authenticated on the webapp and I am not redirected on localhost/glpi/central.php

Comment: I forget to add that I user a webbrowser to execute my script...

Comment: Good point, I happened to make exactly that assumption :). It looks like you found the answer. But since you were still puzzled, I've explained my interpretation of your answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Strange that It could be everything work fine when I set

```
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see.

```
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch1)
```

> Return Values of [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Unless the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, `$file_contents` will not contain the file contents.  They will instead be printed (equivalent of `echo $file_contents`).